# Convert pandas Series to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a Pandas series sf:

```
email
email1@email.com    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
email2@email.com    [2.0, 0.0, 0.0]
email3@email.com    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
email4@email.com    [4.0, 0.0, 0.0]
email5@email.com    [1.0, 0.0, 3.0]
email6@email.com    [1.0, 5.0, 0.0]
```

And I would like to transform it to the following DataFrame:

```
index | email             | list
_____________________________________________
0     | email1@email.com  | [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
1     | email2@email.com  | [2.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2     | email3@email.com  | [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
3     | email4@email.com  | [4.0, 0.0, 0.0]
4     | email5@email.com  | [1.0, 0.0, 3.0]
5     | email6@email.com  | [1.0, 5.0, 0.0]
```

I found a way to do it, but I doubt it's the more efficient one:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=sf.index, columns=['email'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=sf.values, columns=['list'])
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: In more recent versions of pandas, [this can be achieved with a single `reset_index` call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53686321/4909087).

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Rather than create 2 temporary dfs you can just pass these as params within a dict using the DataFrame constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame({'email':sf.index, 'list':sf.values})
```

There are lots of ways to construct a df, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame)

Comment: another great option is to concat if your series have the same axes `pd.concat([sf.index, sf.values], axis=1)`

Answer (score 105):

**to_frame()**:

Starting with the following Series, df:

```
email
email1@email.com    A
email2@email.com    B
email3@email.com    C
dtype: int64
```

I use **to_frame** to convert the series to DataFrame:

```
df = df.to_frame().reset_index()

    email               0
0   email1@email.com    A
1   email2@email.com    B
2   email3@email.com    C
3   email4@email.com    D
```

Now all you need is to rename the column name and name the index column:

```
df = df.rename(columns= {0: 'list'})
df.index.name = 'index'
```

Your DataFrame is ready for further analysis.

Update: I just came across [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503445/assigning-column-names-to-a-pandas-series) where the answers are surprisingly similar to mine here.

Comment: `series_obj.to_frame()` works! I output this class type `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Comment: Why use `to_frame().reset_index()` rather than just `reset_index`? You could even just do `reset_index(name='list')`

Answer (score 36):

One line answer would be

```
myseries.to_frame(name='my_column_name')
```

Or

```
myseries.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)  # As needed
```

Comment: I need to use the converted DataFrame obj in seaborn bar plot, so I need to reset index, say, mydf = myseries.to_frame(name='my_column_name').reset_index()

Answer (score 28):

#### **[`Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html#pandas-series-reset-index) with `name` argument**

Often the use case comes up where a Series needs to be promoted to a DataFrame. But if the Series has no name, then `reset_index` will result in something like,

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=['a', 'b', 'c']).rename_axis('A')
s

A
a    1
b    2
c    3
dtype: int64
```

```
s.reset_index()

   A  0
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  c  3
```

Where you see the column name is "0". We can fix this be specifying a `name` parameter.

```
s.reset_index(name='B')

   A  B
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  c  3
```

```
s.reset_index(name='list')

   A  list
0  a     1
1  b     2
2  c     3
```

---

#### **[`Series.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html)**

If you want to create a DataFrame without promoting the index to a column, use `Series.to_frame`, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52055955/4909087). This *also* supports a name parameter.

```
s.to_frame(name='B')

   B
A   
a  1
b  2
c  3
```

---

#### **[`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) Constructor**

You can also do the same thing as `Series.to_frame` by specifying a `columns` param:

```
pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['B'])

   B
A   
a  1
b  2
c  3
```

Comment: I was wondering why one might use `to_frame` instead of `reset_index`, but is there ever a good reason to use both? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56920021/575530)

Comment: @dumbledad mostly utility. If you want a single col dataframe with index, use to_frame(). If you need two columns (one from the series index and the other from series values itself), go with reset_index().

Comment: And what if I want to convert Series to DataFrame with Seires index used as DataFrame columns names (i.e. transposed)? `to_frame` doesn't seem to have an argument to do this. Thanks.

Comment: @Confounded use to_frame().T to transpose it

Answer (score 12):

Super simple way is also

```
df = pd.DataFrame(series)
```

It will return a DF of 1 column (series values) + 1 index (0....n)

Comment: So, pd.DataFrame(series, columns=['list']).rename_axis('email') might be good.

Answer (score 5):

[`Series.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) can be used to convert a `Series` to `DataFrame`.

```
# The provided name (columnName) will substitute the series name
df = series.to_frame('columnName')
```

---

For example,

```
s = pd.Series(["a", "b", "c"], name="vals")
df = s.to_frame('newCol')
print(df)

   newCol
0    a
1    b
2    c
```

Answer (score 2):

probably graded as a  non-pythonic way to do this but this'll give the result you want in a line:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(zip(email,list))
```

Result:

```
               email               list
0   email1@email.com    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
1   email2@email.com    [2.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2   email3@email.com    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
3   email4@email.com    [4.0, 0.0, 3.0]
4   email5@email.com    [1.0, 5.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The series.to_frame() method and pd.DataFrame() method is used to convert Pandas Series to a DataFrame.

```
import pandas
series = pandas.Series([40, 90, 80, 50, 70])
data_frame = series.to_frame()
print(data_frame)
```

or use the below:

```
data_frame = pandas.DataFrame(series)
```

The pd.concat() method is used to convert multiple Series to a single DataFrame in Python.

```
data_frame = pandas.concat([series1, series2], axis=1)
```