# assigning column names to a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas series

```
object x
Ezh2   2
Hmgb   7
Irf1   1
```

I want to save this as a dataframe with column names Gene and Count respectively
I tried

```
x_df = pd.DataFrame(x,columns = ['Gene','count'])
```

but it does not work.The final form I want is

```
Gene Count
Ezh2   2
Hmgb   7
Irf1   1
```

Can you suggest how to do this

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can create a dict and pass this as the data param to the dataframe constructor:

```
In [235]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'Gene':s.index, 'count':s.values})
df
Out[235]:
   Gene  count
0  Ezh2      2
1  Hmgb      7
2  Irf1      1
```

Alternatively you can create a df from the series, you need to call `reset_index` as the index will be used and then rename the columns:

```
In [237]:

df = pd.DataFrame(s).reset_index()
df.columns = ['Gene', 'count']
df
Out[237]:
   Gene  count
0  Ezh2      2
1  Hmgb      7
2  Irf1      1
```

Answer (score 62):

You can also use the `.to_frame()` method.

If it is a Series, I assume 'Gene' is already the index, and will remain the index after converting it to a DataFrame. The `name` argument of `.to_frame()` will name the column.

```
x = x.to_frame('count')
```

If you want them both as columns, you can reset the index:

```
x = x.to_frame('count').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 14):

If you have a `pd.Series` object `x` with index named 'Gene', you can use `reset_index` and supply the `name` argument:

```
df = x.reset_index(name='count')
```

Here's a demo:

```
x = pd.Series([2, 7, 1], index=['Ezh2', 'Hmgb', 'Irf1'])
x.index.name = 'Gene'

df = x.reset_index(name='count')

print(df)

   Gene  count
0  Ezh2      2
1  Hmgb      7
2  Irf1      1
```