# Converting a Pandas Series to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to do this:

```
get_sent_score_neut_df = 
pandas.Series(get_sent_score_neut).to_frame(name='sentiment- 
neutral').reset_index().apply(lambda x: float(x))
```

And when I want to merge/join it with another DataFrame I created the same way the error I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute '_join_compat'
```

Is there a way to fix that?

That´s the line of code I used to merge/join them:

```
sentMerge = pandas.DataFrame.join(get_sent_score_pos_df, get_sent_score_neut_df)
```

Besides: i have tried to rename the index with ```.reset_index`(name='xyz')``
([assigning column names to a pandas series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503445/assigning-column-names-to-a-pandas-series)) which causes my IDE to responed with "unexpected argument".

Comment: Hi! Would you please share a sample of the data you are using?

Comment: Basically it´s just some floats, which are originally stored in json.        "sentiment-neg": "0.141",
        "sentiment-neu": "0.727",
        "sentiment-pos": "0.132",
        "sentiment-compound": "-0.3254"