# pandas Series to Dataframe using Series indexes as columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series, like this:

```
series = pd.Series({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3})
```

I want to convert it to a dataframe like this:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
```

`pd.Series.to_frame()` doesn't work, it got result like,

```
    0
a   1
b   2
c   3
```

How can I construct a DataFrame from Series, with index of Series as columns?

Comment: `series.to_frame().T`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python, best way to convert a pandas series into a pandas dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097916/python-best-way-to-convert-a-pandas-series-into-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: They are different. My question focus on using Series' index as columns.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can also try this :

```
df = DataFrame(series).transpose()
```

Using the transpose() function you can interchange the indices and the columns.
The output looks like this :

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
```

Comment: If you haven't imported DataFrame separately you need to write it as :    `df = pd.DataFrame(series).transpose() `

Comment: Done. The output is exactly what is desired.

Comment: MaxU's comment gave the best answer.

    series.to_frame().T

Comment: Warning : this method works very well for small series, but if you use longer ones, the complexity exploses.

For me, it ran for 21 seconds for a single series of 2755 columns.

Answer (score 36):

You don't need the transposition step, just wrap your Series inside a list and pass it to the [**`DataFrame`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame([series])

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

---

Alternatively, call [**`Series.to_frame`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html), then transpose using the shortcut `.T`:

```
series.to_frame().T

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([series])` is better than `transpose`. You don't have to remember what goes to index at when, and then what gets moved to columns.

Answer (score 8):

you can also try this:

`a = pd.Series.to_frame(series)`

`a['id'] = list(a.index)`

Explanation:
The 1st line convert the series into a single-column DataFrame.
The 2nd line add an column to this DataFrame with the value same as the index.

Comment: A little bit of an explanation as to how this works would be helpful. Remember than our answers are supposed to be instructive!

Comment: This doesn't produce the expected result.

Answer (score 8):

Try reset_index. It will convert your index into a column in your dataframe.

```
df = series.to_frame().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 3):

This

```
pd.DataFrame([series]) #method 1
```

produces a slightly different result than

```
series.to_frame().T #method 2
```

With method 1, the elements in the resulted dataframe retain the same type. e.g. an int64 in series will be kept as an int64.

With method 2, the elements in the resulted dataframe become objects IF there is an object type element anywhere in the series. e.g. an int64 in series will be become an object type.

This difference may cause different behaviors in your subsequent operations depending on the version of pandas.