# All the ways to construct DataFrame() from data

Tags: python, pandas

The parameters section of the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) for `DataFrame` (as of `pandas` 2.0.0) begins:

> **data : *ndarray (structured or homogeneous), Iterable, dict, or DataFrame***
>
> Dict can contain Series, arrays, constants, dataclass or list-like objects. If data is a dict, column order follows insertion-order. If a dict contains Series which have an index defined, it is aligned by its index. This alignment also occurs if data is a Series or a DataFrame itself. Alignment is done on Series/DataFrame inputs.
>
> If data is a list of dicts, column order follows insertion-order.

The description points to valid input types (i.e., *ndarray, Iterable, dict, or DataFrame*) **but does not completely describe *how* the constructor will turn the `data` into a `DataFrame`**. It seems like somewhat of a black box. Should I be able to predict, based on the documentation, that, say, passing a `list` containing a single `Series` and no other arguments will give a result that looks like `Series.to_frame().T` (although the dtypes may differ; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56713499) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74385065))?

The purpose of this question is to solicit answers that **classify the different ways of passing data to a `DataFrame()` via `data`, according to how the constructor puts or massages the data into the `DataFrame`**. It is necessarily a broad question, but there should be a finite number of cases given that the constructor is, you know, implemented in code. I'm interested in this question and would be willing to dig through the source code a little to discover the answer; however, I think others with more experience may have insights to share here before I do that.

This is a single question about rules broadly, and I believe its answers belong together in one place. However, since it is broad, I will provide some specific sub-questions to get us started:

- For `iterable`s, what container and element combinations are valid? Without needing to try it, should I be able to predict what will happen if I pass a `list` of `DataFrames` or a `Series` of `Series`? Which axis is used when a `Series` input is "aligned by its index"? Does the treatment depend at all on what its elements are?
- How do the container and element types passed via `data` affect how the `DataFrame` will be put together? Should I be able to predict how the data will be aligned along the axes of the resulting `DataFrame` based on knowledge of `data` alone? I don't know if the answer is obvious, but in either case I do not see it documented.
- If I think of a `DataFrame` as "a dict-like container for `Series` objects" (as docs suggest), what are the intuitive rules governing how `data` gets interpreted (loosely) into keys and values?

I'm open to suggestions for improving the question, but I do think it's a question that needs to be asked and I did not find a similar question on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the documentation, it's sometimes useful to read the tests, especially `test_constructors.py` in your case. There are many ways to build a DataFrame.

Too long to describe all ways, take a look to [`test_constructors.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.0.0/pandas/tests/frame/test_constructors.py#L77)

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb:

- If `data` is `list`like, items become rows
- If `data` is `dict`like, items become columns (with keys as column names).

Then for *items within* `data`:

- If *items* are `dict`like, item keys become the names of the other axis (i.e., `columns` if `data` was `list`like, `index` if `data` was `dict`like).

Finally, `Series` is `dict`like mapping `index` to values; `DataFrame` is `dict`like mapping `columns` to `Series`.