# pandas Series to Dataframe using Series indexes as columns with multiple values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

i have a series that i need it in Dataframe. so the series looks like this.

```
column1              [-333, -333, -3,3 -33, -33, ...
column2              [-121.0, -431.0, -41.0, -1.0, -1.0, ...
column3              [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
column4              [-451.0, -5121.0, -41.0, -21.0, -4121.0, ...
column5              [1451.0, 19851.0, 1451.0, 1451.0, 1941.0, ...
```

i tried to implement this [post (pandas-series-to-dataframe-using-series-indexes-as-columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224319/pandas-series-to-dataframe-using-series-indexes-as-columns) but i got this dataframe (i'm illustrating only for one column here) which all the value in a list is in one row of the dataframe:

```
     column1    

0    [-9.0, 
     -811.0, 
     -71.0, 
     -691.0, 
     -41.0, ...
```

is there any way to convert pandas series into dataframe while the value is a list and column value is the index.

EDIT:

the data as `srs.head().to_dict()`

```
{'column1': masked_array(data=[-4524, -41144, -44314,...,444,44005,  44],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `explode`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(srs).T.explode(list(srs.index))
```