# Why use to_frame before reset_index?

Tags: pandas

Using a data set like this one

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(20, 3)), columns=['user_id','module_id','week'])
```

we often see this pattern:

```python
df.groupby(['user_id'])['module_id'].count().to_frame().reset_index().rename({'module_id':'count'}, axis='columns')
```

But we get exactly the same result from

```python
df.groupby(['user_id'])['module_id'].count().reset_index(name='count')
```

(N.B. we need the additional `rename` in the former because `reset_index` on Series ([here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html)) includes a `name` parameter and returns a data frame, while `reset_index` on DataFrame ([here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)) does not include the `name` parameter.)

Is there any advantage in using `to_frame` first?

(I wondered if it might be an artefact of earlier versions of pandas, but that looks unlikely:

- `Series.reset_index` was added in [this commit](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/12094e9a6bfe0e941289eb2b20863a792ba38b58) on the 27th of January 2012.
- `Series.to_frame` was added in [this commit](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/844bcff0917af28907483be3cd927a07edb8f53d) on the 13th of October 2013.

So `Series.reset_index` was available over a year before `Series.to_frame`.)

Comment: I always do the second approach. Never seen the first pattern before...The only reason you want to use to_frame() is to keep seires index while getting a dataframe. It does not make sense to use it before reset_index

Comment: i don't think the first approach is required. `.to_frame()` is generally used to convert a series to dataframe which reset_index() already does for you here. However i prefer `groupby().size()` more than count (its faster IMO)

Answer (score 1):

There is no noticeable advantage of using `to_frame()`. Both approaches can be used to achieve the same result. It is common in pandas to use multiple approaches for solving a problem. The only advantage I can think of is that for larger sets of data, it maybe more convenient to have a dataframe view first before resetting the index. If we take your dataframe as an example, you will find that `to_frame()` displays a dataframe view that maybe useful to understand the data in terms of a neat dataframe table v/s a `count` series. Also, the usage of `to_frame()` makes the intent more clear to a new user who looks at your code for the first time.

The example dataframe:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(20, 3)), columns=['user_i
   ...: d','module_id','week'])

In [8]: df.head()
Out[8]:
   user_id  module_id  week
0        3          4     4
1        1          3     4
2        1          2     2
3        1          3     4
4        1          2     2
```

The `count()` function returns a Series:

```
In [18]: test1 = df.groupby(['user_id'])['module_id'].count()

In [19]: type(test1)
Out[19]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [20]: test1
Out[20]:
user_id
0    2
1    7
2    4
3    6
4    1
Name: module_id, dtype: int64

In [21]: test1.index
Out[21]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64', name='user_id')
```

Using `to_frame` makes it explicit that you intend to convert the Series to a Dataframe. The index here is `user_id`:

```
In [22]: test1.to_frame()
Out[22]:
         module_id
user_id
0                2
1                7
2                4
3                6
4                1
```

And now we reset the index and rename the column using Dataframe.rename. As you rightly pointed, `Dataframe.reset_index()` does not have a `name` parameter and therefore, we will have to rename the column explicitly.

```
In [24]: testdf1 = test1.to_frame().reset_index().rename({'module_id':'count'}, axis='columns')

In [25]: testdf1
Out[25]:
   user_id  count
0        0      2
1        1      7
2        2      4
3        3      6
4        4      1
```

Now lets look at the other case. We will use the same `count()` series `test1` but rename it as `test2` to differentiate between the two approaches. In other words, `test1` is equal to `test2`.

```
In [26]: test2 = df.groupby(['user_id'])['module_id'].count()

In [27]: test2
Out[27]:
user_id
0    2
1    7
2    4
3    6
4    1
Name: module_id, dtype: int64

In [28]: test2.reset_index()
Out[28]:
   user_id  module_id
0        0          2
1        1          7
2        2          4
3        3          6
4        4          1

In [30]: testdf2 = test2.reset_index(name='count')

In [31]: testdf1 == testdf2
Out[31]:
   user_id  count
0     True   True
1     True   True
2     True   True
3     True   True
4     True   True
```

As you can see both dataframes are equivalent, and in the second approach we just had to use `reset_index(name='count')` to both reset the index and rename the column name because `Series.reset_index()` does have a `name` parameter.

The second case has lesser code but is less readable for new eyes and I'd prefer the first approach of using `to_frame()` because it makes the intent clear: "Convert this count series to a dataframe and rename the column 'module_id' to 'count'".