# Is there a way to un-nesting a pandas dataframe in a python3 jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, dimensionality-reduction

I am importing a json file into a python3 jupyter notebook. The json file has the format

1. object

   - rooms [26 elements]

     - 0

       - turns

         - fromBathroom
         - fromParking
       - distances

         - dfromBathroom
         - dfromParking
       - depth
       - area
     - 1

       - .... etc.
   - name

I am importing the json file in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open("rooms.json") as file:
  data = json.load(file)
df = json_normalize(data['rooms'])
```

I am now trying to plot each of the 6 dimensions against each other in a matrix-like format, with 36 total graphs.

I am trying to this the following way:

```
col_features = ['fromBathroom', 'fromParking', 'dfromBathroom', 'dfromParking', 'depth', 'area']
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df[col_features], alpha = .2, figsize = (14,8))
```

This does not work, as I am getting an error that reads:
KeyError: "['fromBathroom' 'fromParking' 'dfromBathroom' 'dfromParking'] not in index"

This is because those features are nested in 'turns' and 'distances' in the json file. Is there a way to un-nest these features so that I can index into the dataframe the same way I can for depth and area to get the values?

Thank you for any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could extract `df1 = df['turns']`, `df2 = df['distances']` and `df3 = df['areas', 'depth]` and then do a `df4 = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], join='inner', axis=1)` [see pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes)

or directly : `pd.concat([df['turns'], df['distances'], df['areas', 'depth]], join='inner', axis=1)`

***EDIT :***

I tried something, I hope it is what you are looking for :

[link to the image with the code and the results I get with Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOf2g.png)

```
df1 = df['turns']
df2 = df['distances']
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df['depth'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(df['area'])
df_recomposed = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4], join='inner', axis=1)
```

or [Pandas - How to flatten a hierarchical index in columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507794/pandas-how-to-flatten-a-hierarchical-index-in-columns?answertab=active#tab-top)

where `df.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]` should be what you are looking for

Comment: That's a good idea! Trying to do that now, except when I index into the dataframe with 'turns' and 'distances', I get a KeyError. When I say `print(df['area'])`, I get a series object of the correct values. Not sure why one works and the other doesn't :(

Comment: Try to convert each serie into a dataframe :

[See this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097916/convert-pandas-series-to-dataframe?answertab=active#tab-top)